# Visual Studio 2019 & 2022 (Preview) not finding .NET 6 SDK on launch - mac osx

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to run a C# .NET Core project locally on Mac and encountering some issues both on Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.

Firstly, every time on loading up the project in Visual Studio, I get a red cross beside each directory in the file tree of the project and a message at the top of the screen to say:

> .NET 6.0 SDK is required to build this application and is not installed.

The console says:

> error: Unknown MSBuild failure. Please try building the project again
> Unable to create package spec for project.

In Visual Studio Preferences>SDK Locations>.Net Core, I get an error to say 'SDKs found: None' even though in the boxes below it's showing SDK's that are found, as below. If I change the location then change it back, the red crosses next to the directories disappear in the file tree but the build still fails and I still have the error message to say .NET 6.0 SDK is required to build.

[image]

In project options, the target framework is set to .NET 6.0 and it shows as installed.

I have tried completely uninstalling dotnet and reinstalling both from the browser and using homebrew, reinstalling Visual Studio, adding a global.json file with sdk version, and checking dotnet is definitely installed.

`$ dotnet --info` in terminal produces the following:

[image]

What I do notice is the 'Base Path' here is different to the path in preferences (in the picture above). I'm not sure if this could be related, or if this could be a path related issue but possibly someone might be able to advise with more knowledge than me.

Thank you.

Comment: I had this problem where it would try to install over and over, and still would never find it. I did `brew remove dotnet` and then installed from Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The location of the sdk should be as below ( attached screenshot as well )

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
```

instead of

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me! - Thanks for sharing... It's quite of annoying to face this type of issues.

Comment: Same here! It worked! Thanx Abiranjan!